# How to wildcard redirect in javascript

Tags: javascript

How to i want to wildcard redirect in javascript. I placed this code in index.html but the wildcard redirect did not work.
When I access the rootdomain.com it redirects to test.example.com
But when I access the rootdomain.com/path it doesn't redirect to test.example.com/path

```
<script>

    setInterval(function(){ 
        number = document.getElementById("number").innerHTML;
        var url1 = 'test.';
        var url2 = 'example';
        var url3 = '.com';
        if (number > 0) {
            number--;
        }
        document.getElementById("number").innerHTML = number; 
        if (number == 0) {
            window.location.replace('https://' + url1 + url2 + url3 + + window.location.pathname);
        }
     }, 1000);
    
</script>
```

I tried a simple code, but still did not work:

```
<script>
    window.setTimeout(function(){

        // Move to a new location or you can do something else
        window.location.href = "https://test.example.com" + window.location.pathname;

    }, 5000);

</script>


<h1>Wait 5seconds</h1>
```

Thank You

Comment: why do you have two `+` signs after `url3`?

Comment: Thanks for ur response, That was a mistake, I tried to remove it but the result is still the same:
Not Found
The requested URL was not found on this server.

Additionally, a 404 Not Found error was encountered while trying to use an ErrorDocument to handle the request.

Comment: What is the destination that you expect to reach? `https://test.example.com/...` ?

Comment: any path, whatever the user type after the domain

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try it:

```
window.location = 'https://' + url1 + url2 + url3 +   window.location.host+window.location.pathname;
```

Comment: @Winie can you share new URL(after redirect) that show error?

Comment: my domain: https://1.phsensei.com/anypath does not redirects to https://note.legendsfreenetph.com/anypath  But when i access the 1.phsensei.com , it redirects to note.legendsfreenetph.com

Comment: I also tried this, but still the same:
<script>
setTimeout(function(){ 
window.location.replace("https://note.legendsfreenetph.com/" + window.location.pathname);

}, 3000);
</script>
<h1>Wait 3 seconds</h1>

Comment: @Winie Hey i tried `setTimeout(function() { location.href = "https://test.example.com" + location.pathname }, 5000)` and it's work and i checked 1.phsensei.com/anypath there's no js code on it it's just Not Found Message how do you expect to redirect user to other page when there's nothing to handle that ?

Comment: Because i wrote the js code in the root directory not in /anypath. I dont know what path user would access.

Comment: @Winie Write it in your 404 file